# Surpress output when calling matlab live script from other live script

Tags: matlab

I have a live script (main.mlx) that is calling two other live scripts (sub1.mlx, sub2.mlx). I want the output to be shown when calling the subscripts by themself but not when I call the main script, though I want to display something in the main script. I tried to put a semicolon behind the subscript calls in main script.

**Minimum working example**

main.mlx:

```
clear vars

sub1;
sub2;
```

sub1.mlx:

```
syms A1 B1

A1 = B1
```

sub2.mlx:

```
syms A2 B2

A2 = B2
```

Expected output: 
None

Output:

[image]

**What I tried** (unsuccessfully):

```
clear vars

run('sub1.mlx');
run('sub2.mlx');
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is:

```
clear vars
out1=evalc('sub1');
out2=evalc('sub2');
```

where out1 and out2 are optional to catch the output.

Answer (score 2):

The following golden rule can be applied to any MATLAB coding, and is applicable here

> Always suppress the display of assignments using `;`, and explicitly display variables separately when required.

In this case, we can do the following:

- Inside `main.mlx`, we write

  ```
  % Call the sub scripts without output
  bDisp = false;
  sub1; 
  sub2;
  ```
- Inside `sub1.mlx` and `sub2.mlx`, you can structure your outputs to be more explicit

  ```
  % By default (when running this script alone), display things
  if ~exist( 'bDisp', 'var' )
      bDisp = true;
  end

  syms A1 B1
  % Terminate the assignment with a semi-colon to suppress output
  A1 = B1;
  % Explicitly display A1 here (if bDisp is enabled)
  if bDisp
      A1 % disp(A1) would be even more verbose, but doesn't show "A1 = "
  end
  ```

This method gives you control over when to display things, regardless where you're calling them from.

You could make the default check (at the top of `sub1.mlx`/`sub2.mlx`) more complicated if you want. For instance you could use `dbstack` to determine where the executing code was called from (i.e. which function), but live scripts get a bit funky with the stack.